# Does not move toolstrip

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2010, mono

Not moved toolstrip in ubuntu.
I create in vs 2010 with Mono.
In Windows Seven all rigth.

because of what this can happen?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Is the toolstrip moveable in ubuntu but not in Windows, or not moveable in ubuntu but moveable in Windows?  What is the desired behavior?  Can you post some code?

Comment: I use simply toolstrip. should move in windows and in Ubuntu

Comment: What do you mean with "moveable" ? If you mean to move the menu from the top to the bottom or left etc... never seen this `ToolStrip` capability before ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mono's ToolStrip implementation does not support dragging.